# PyGTK Icon Blurry in Ubuntu

Tags: python, icons, pygtk, ubuntu-10.10, blurry

When using an `SVG` file as the icon of a `PyGTK` window set by the function:

`set_icon_from_file("icon.svg")`,

the icon appears blurry when viewed from the Alt-Tab view and Unity Launcher Bar in Ubuntu 11.10.

---

Is there a simple way to prevent the icon from becoming blurred and to maintain its normal quality?

Comment: Have you checked so that the icon has the right hight:width ratio and resolution etc set compared to other icons that don't look blurry - just a hunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity and Gnome3 only display icons in the full resolution if you define them in a suitable .desktop file e.g. in `~/.local/share/applications/` and launch the application with this. There you can supply your SVG file and it will be used in full resolution.

If you want to make sure the desktop environment finds the correct icon in any way, according to [this](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/ApplicationBased) you should make sure to set the correct WM_CLASS, like `gtk.gdk.set_program_class("my_app")`. Then call your .desktop file `my_app.desktop`.

Oh, and you should call `gtk.gdk.set_program_class()` before `set_icon_from_file()`, otherwise you will still have the crappy low-res image. The latter is only required if you also run your app on Windows, which does not know the .desktop file.